# Arduino - How can i get a string command and match it with if statements?

Tags: c, arduino

I have this following code, which is working for any string to send and receive `hello world`. But how can i send specific string and use if then else ?

for example, when i send following its always sending hello world only but how can i do

```
echo "command1" | nc -4u localhost 21
echo "command2  | nc -4u localhsot 21
```

on receive i want to parse them with if then else but its not working:

```
if ( packetBuffer == "command1" ) { 

else if ( packetBuffer == "command2") { 

} else {

}
```

code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

byte mac[]={0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xAD, 0xDE};
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,2);
unsigned int localPort = 21;

char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "hello world";
EthernetUDP Udp;

char          r1[] = "1";
char          r2[] = "2";
char          r3[] = "3";

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if(packetSize) {
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.read(packetBuffer,UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Udp.write(packetBuffer);

      if ( !strcmp(packetBuffer, "command1") ) {
        Udp.write(r1);
      } else if ( !strcmp(packetBuffer, "command2") ) {
        Udp.write(r2);
      } else {
        Udp.write(r3);
      }

    Udp.endPacket();
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the equality operator `==`, you're comparing the pointers.

In your case, you can to compare the content, using `strcmp()` for "String Compare".

```
if ( !strcmp(packetBuffer, "command1") ) { 

else if ( !strcmp(packetBuffer, "command2") ) { 

} else {

}
```

Note that `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings match, and `-1` or `+1` otherwise (depending on alphabetical order).

Comment: You're probably receiving `\n` (or `\r\n`) at the end of the message. That would explain why the comparison fails. You can easily find out by logging the messages to the serial port.

Comment: The best is to write a trimming function that will scan the string, starting from the end and replace '\n' or '\r' with a `\0`, so as to reduce the string length.

Comment: The lazy solution is: `*strrchr(packetBuffer,'\n')=0;`

Comment: `echo` is adding the `\n`. You can `echo -n` to avoid this, but i'm not sure `nc` would like it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm tired of this game. I gave you an accurate answer on a specific problem. Then you changed the question and asked for more. This is not honest, you should not change the original question that much, it doesn't make any sense now. Moreover, you should not delete your comments, now it looks like i'm talking to myself.

Comment: NO i did not mean that, i removed the comments because it does not allow long list of comments, so i kept your comments only which is valuable.

Comment: Did you try with `!strcmp(packetBuffer, "command1\n")` and `!strcmp(packetBuffer, "command1\r\n")` ? Also, did you try to log `packetBuffer` to the serial port ?

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!! It works finally. How strange \n or \r\n i needed to add. How strange!!!!! echo -e or printf still create new lines, wow!!! strange.